# How to use pointer in matlab to change the original variable?

Tags: matlab, pointers

I tried to use the pointer in matlab. The following code didn't change the value of `x` after set `xptr.value=4;`. I don't understand why.

```
x=3;
xptr=libpointer('doublePtr',x);
xptr.value=4;
```

Comment: MATLAB doesn't work that way.  MATLAB works by copy-on-write, which means that `x` will only change only if it changes itself.  It has no effect when you do this via a pointer.  Also as gnovice mentions, `x` is only used to initialize the value of `xptr`.

Comment: Matlab has pointer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supposed to change the value of `x`, since `x` is only used to *initialize* the value of `xptr`. Note this line from [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/libpointer.html) (emphasis mine):

> `p = libpointer(DataType,Value)` creates pointer initialized to **a copy** of `Value`.